# How do I add files to a VLC playlist from the command line on OS X?

Tags: macos, command-line, vlc-media-player

I have a Mac across the room hooked up to a big monitor. I do a lot of programming on a Linux netbook, and have lots of terminals open. It'd be nice if I could run a script called something like "add2vlc" which would take a file and push it on the end of the VLC playlist.

Is there any way of doing this?

On Windows and Linux, you can call vlc (or vlc.exe) with --playlist-enqueue. But /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/VLC cannot be called with --playlist-enqueue.

I see that in /Applications/VLC.app/Contents/MacOS/share/lua/ there is all sorts of Lua code to script VLC, but I don't really know Lua and can't seem to find documentation that describes how I might use this code to add stuff to the playlist.

If I enable VLC's RC module, VLC doesn't start. Neither does it start with the ncurses controller. Do I need to recompile VLC to get this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found that most of what I need to do can be done with AppleScript. I've made a little VLC control script in Ruby that uses RubyOSA. Basically, all I want to do is play/pause and add stuff to the playlist. I've put it up here: [vlc-control](https://bitbucket.org/tommorris/vlc-control/src).

Comment: The link seems to be broken. Has it moved?

Comment: Appears to be at https://bitbucket.org/tommorris/vlc-control/src

Comment: Yes, alas Bitbucket removed the custom domain stuff.

Answer (score 2):

Just came across this old post.

I don't know about Macs but on Windows you can run the following to have a playlist:

```
vlc.exe file1 file2
```

(You would typically need quotes on Windows. "file1")

Alternatively, create a .pls file and specify that when starting vlc.

```
vlc.exe --config vlcrc playlist2.pls
```

An example playlist file (playlist2.pls):

```
[playlist]

NumberOfEntries=2

File1=C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\My Music\f1.mp3
Title1=f1

File2=File1=C:\Documents and Settings\user\My Documents\My Music\f2.mp3
Title2=f2
```

Comment: That might work because I have noticed that VLC seems to *add* everything you play to playlist (until it is restarted).

Answer (score 2):

I have tried all keys from "a to z" and "A to Z", and I found that if you press B (capital b) you will find a "file browser", so you can add files from there.

That worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: Leave that, here is something promising

http://n0tablog.wordpress.com/2009/02/09/controlling-vlc-via-rc-remote-control-interface-using-a-unix-domain-socket-and-no-programming/

Basically, you first enable the RC interface from the advanced options, restart vlc and start sending commands over the socket you setup. Check out the pretty pictures in the blog.

I have tested this with my VLC  1.1.5 and it seems to be working

Answer (score 0):

Had the same challenge on Windows. Turns out a .m3u playlist is pretty forgiving - you can just dump the file names into it and VLC will play it!

Using powershell, I dig through all folders in **Z:\Music** (excluding non-music ones) and dump them in **playlist.m3u on the desktop**:

```
ls z:\music -Recurse -Force -Exclude *.jpg,*.jpeg,*.png,*.bmp,*.txt | ? {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false} | % {$_.FullName | Out-File C:\Users\user\Desktop\playlist.m3u -append}
```